# How to turn off scroll event when condition is not met & LISTEN BACK ON when condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, event-handling

I would like to listen on/off scroll event only when it's necessary. As for now, everytime I `off` the event, it doesn't listen back `on`. As an example on code below, I would love to turn off the scroll event when the condition is not met AND THEN LISTEN BACK ON when the condition is met.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', '[data-apple]', function() {
  const scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  const height = $('[data-apple]').outerHeight();
  const offset = 52;
        
  if (scroll > offset && scroll < height + offset){
    // Listen to scroll
    console.log('listen');
  } else {
    // Stop listening to scroll
    $(window).off('scroll', '[data-apple]');
  }
  
});
```

```css
body { background: wheat; min-height: 2000px; }
.apple { height: 200px; background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-apple class="apple">
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than enabling/disabling event handlers, why not just put the logic to be executed within the relevant parts of your `if` condition in the `scroll` handler?

Comment: But if I do it inside `if` in `$(window).scroll`, it will keeps on listening to scroll event even when the `if` is not met right? would it not be expensive?

Comment: It depends on the logic in the handler. Consider adding a debounce if you're concerned with scrolling performance

Comment: So this means `$(window).on('scroll', function() { if (condition) { // Do stuff } });` is the right way to go? I shouldn't worry too much of the performance. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Well, you should still worry about performance as performing a lot of logic in a `scroll` event can cause the UI to stutter, but I'd say only worry about it when it becomes an issue